# Invoke Anchor program from rust program

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust

The Anchor book describes how to perform a CPI from Anchor, but it requires importing both programs and passing in the Context from one to another. If I want to invoke (say a Serum DEX program) from a program built on rust, how would I do so?

Comment: Serum DEX (well the main one https://github.com/project-serum/serum-dex) is not an Anchor program.

Comment: Sorry I was more talking about Serum Swap (https://github.com/project-serum/swap/blob/master/programs/swap/src/lib.rs)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it please follow the steps [[https://github.com/project-serum/serum-dex/tree/master/dex]](https://github.com/project-serum/serum-dex/tree/master/dex)

Comment: It seems like that repository is not written in anchor? I'm more curious about something like [serum swap](https://github.com/project-serum/swap/blob/master/programs/swap/src/lib.rs) , where the derived Swap account includes the MarketAccounts struct, and I'm not sure how to handle this in Rust.